# How to set custom form input field for "Price"?

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms

I have a basic html form that adds some data to the page using PHP.  I want to make this form field a "Price" field.  My html is:

```
<input class="bids" name="comment" id="comment" tabindex="4" />
```

How can I fix this field so that users can't enter random letters, dollar signs, dashes, or other weird formats.  I want the output to be whole dollars.  Sorry I'm a complete programming moron. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use javascript with regex to only allow digits for the client side.  You should also do a server side check using php & regex to make sure the post data only contains digits.

Here is a javascript function that checks to make sure that a particular field input contains only numbers.

```
function IsNumeric(numstr)
{
    if (numstr.match(/^\d+$/ ) ) {

        alert("Valid number");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Only numeric values are allowed");
    }
}
```

Take a look at [this javascript regex guide](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/re.shtml) to help you.

Don't forget to do the PHP checking on the server side as well...

The PHP regex function would look something like:

```
preg_match('/[0-9]+/', $numstr);
```

Comment: Wow awesome.  So I would wrap that function in script tags and put in my header?  Then how would I tie it to my form submit?  (sorry, total complete programming noob!)

Comment: Yes, in the <head></head> section.

Answer (score 0):

give the form the onsubmit event

```
<form blah ... onsubmit="return proof(this)">
```

your proof function does something like:

```
var proof = function(form){
    value = form.comment;
    var strReg = "^([0-9\.\-])";
    var regex = new RegExp(strReg);

    return(regex.test(value));
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  Where would I put the proof function?  header? javacript?  (sorry)

Comment: header would be god. inner a <script> tag ;-)
and give the user a hint, that something does not work well ... and for sure check on the server as well, because actually i am able to send your server JS evaluated values

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to restrict input box input to number and a decimal point. It uses jquery plugin caret to get current position of the input as well as length of selection.
You can fix number of digits as well as number of decimal points

```
$("#mPrice").live(
"keydown keyup",function(event) {
checkNumberDecimal(event,'mPrice',2,7);});


function checkNumberDecimal(event,element,noDecimal,noDigit)
{

var number = $('#'+element).val();
var caretlength = $('#'+element).caret().text.length;
var position = $('#'+element).caret().start;
var flagDecimal=0;
var flagDigit=0;


if(number.indexOf('.') != -1)
{
var n = number.substring(number.indexOf('.')+1);
if(caretlength <=1 )
  {
   if(n.length >= noDecimal &&  (number.length - position) < (noDecimal+1))
   flagDecimal=1;

if(noDigit > -1)
{
 if(number.length >= (noDigit+1))
 flagDigit = 1;
} 
} else if(position == (number.length - (n.length+1)))
{ 
    if(noDigit > -1)
      {
       if(number.length >= (noDigit+1))
         flagDigit = 1;
      } 
}
 }
 else
{
 if(caretlength <=1)
  if(noDigit > -1) 
   {
    if(number.length  >= (noDigit - noDecimal))
           { flagDigit = 1;}
 } 
 }


 // Allow: backspace (8), delete (46), tab (9), escape (27), enter (13), decimal (110),         period (190), 0-9 (48-57), 0-9 (96-105)
 // keypad: 0-9 (48-57), a-z (65-90) period (190)
 // numpad: 0-9 (96-105), decimal (110)
 // capslock (20)
 // end (35), home (36) left arrow (37), up arrow (38), right arrow (39), down arrow (   (40)

    if ((number.indexOf('.') < 0 && noDecimal > 0 && (event.keyCode ==110 ||    event.keyCode == 190)) || event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 9  || event.keyCode == 27 || event.keyCode == 13 || 
         // Allow: Ctrl+A
        (event.keyCode == 65 && event.ctrlKey === true) ||
         // Allow: home, end, left, right
        (event.keyCode >= 35 && event.keyCode <= 39)) {
             // let it happen, don't do anything
             return;
    }
     else{
        // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
        if (flagDecimal === 1 || flagDigit === 1 || event.shiftKey || (event.keyCode <  48 || event.keyCode > 57) && (event.keyCode < 96 || event.keyCode > 105 )) {
            event.preventDefault(); 
        }   
    } 
 }
```

Comment: Have you read the accepted answer? What your answer adds to the accepted one?